# How can I help the autocomplete prompt me for the keys that the hook returns?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I made a hook that returns me one of the options for the text, depending on the set region, but I don't understand which generic is needed so that on the output I get the object keys available to me.
Currently no keys are recognized.

The code of the hook itself with a non-working generic:

```js
interface Translate {
    [keys: string]: {
        ru: string
        en: string
    }
}

export function useTranslate<T extends Translate, R extends keyof T>(translate: T) {
    const lang = Location.language
    const response: { [keys: R]: string } = {}

    Object.keys(translate).forEach(name => {
        if (lang === 'ru-RU') {
            response[name] = translate[name].ru
        } else {
            response[name] = translate[name].en
        }
    })

    return response
}
```

Hook example:

```js
    const translate = useTranslate({
        home: {
            en: 'Home',
            ru: 'Главная',
        },
        shop: {
            en: 'Shop',
            ru: 'Магазин',
        },
        suppliers: {
            en: 'Suppliers',
            ru: 'Поставщикам',
        },
        faq: {
            en: 'FAQ',
            ru: 'FAQ',
        },
        reviews: {
            en: 'Reviews',
            ru: 'Отзывы',
        },
    })

//return if EN region {
home: 'Home',
shop: 'Shop',
...
}
//return if RU region {
home: 'Главная',
shop: 'Магазин',
...
}
```

Returns EN or RU, just one thing.

TODO: force autocomplete to prompt which keys I can refer to.

Thank you in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be my solution. The method has typesafe parameters and return value, but uses `any` internal. I hope thats okay for you.

```js
export function useTranslate<T extends Translate>(translate: T): Record<keyof T, string> {
    const lang = Location.language;
    const response: any = {};

    Object.keys(translate).forEach(name => {
        if (lang === 'ru-RU') {
            response[name] = translate[name].ru
        } else {
            response[name] = translate[name].en
        }
    })

    return response
}
```